# Double reverse proxy keep proxy header

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx reverse proxy that add proxy headers like:

```
proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
proxy_set_header    Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header    Connection         $http_connection;

proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
```

But I don't want to add those headers if the reverse is already behind another (ie: I find already some proxy headers on the request).

How can I do that? Thanks